# Programmatically select text in a contenteditable HTML element?

Tags: javascript, selection, contenteditable

In JavaScript, it's possible to programmatically select text in an `input` or `textarea` element. You can focus an input with `ipt.focus()`, and then select its contents with [`ipt.select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.select). You can even select a specific range with [`ipt.setSelectionRange(from,to)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Input.setSelectionRange).

My question is: is there any way to do this in a `contenteditable` element too?

I found that I can do `elem.focus()`, to put the caret in a `contenteditable` element, but subsequently running `elem.select()` doesn't work (and nor does `setSelectionRange`). I can't find anything on the web about it, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing...

By the way, if it makes any difference, I only need it to work in Google Chrome, as this is for a Chrome extension.

Comment: Modern [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61217786/8112776):  **`window.getSelection().selectAllChildren( element );`**  ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Selection/selectAllChildren))

Answer (score 216, accepted):

If you want to select all the content of an element (contenteditable or not) in Chrome, here's how. This will also work in Firefox, Safari 3+, Opera 9+ (possibly earlier versions too) and IE 9. You can also create selections down to the character level. The APIs you need are DOM Range (current spec is [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html), see also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:range)) and Selection, which is being specified as part of a [new Range spec](http://html5.org/specs/dom-range.html) ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection)).

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

var el = document.getElementById("foo");
selectElementContents(el);
```

Comment: For extra compatibilty you should call `selectElementContents()` in a `setTimeout()` or `requestAnimationFrame()` if called from an `onfocus`. See http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/MgASG/1/show/

Comment: @Dylan: I'm not sure: the question mentions that the OP is already using `focus()`.

Comment: @Rudie *Compatibility* for which application?

Comment: Works great on desktop.  On mobile browsers, does not work.  No selection made.  Tried Safari and Chrome on iPhone iOS 11.

Comment: @campbell: It does work on Safari at least on iOS, **provided you already have a selection**. Otherwise no, the browser simply does not allow JavaScript to show a selection, presumably for user experience reasons.

Comment: Doesn't work if the element is `display:none;`  So i just moved the element off screen...Thanks for the code!

Comment: There's a faster way using `selectAllChildren()`. See my answer below.

Comment: @Catalin `selectAllChildren()` was around in 2011 and I would have been aware of it, so why I didn't suggest it is unclear. I'm guessing it may have had some compatibility issues. I agree it's safe to use it now.

Answer (score 36):

In addition to [Tim Downs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150060/1250044), i made a solution that work even in oldIE:

```
var selectText = function() {
  var range, selection;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(this);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
};

document.getElementById('foo').ondblclick = selectText;​
```

Tested in IE 8+, Firefox 3+, Opera 9+, & Chrome 2+. Even I've set it up into a jQuery plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function() {
  var range, selection;
  return this.each(function() {
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(this);
      range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection();
      range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(this);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  });
};

$('#foo').on('dblclick', function() {
  $(this).selectText();
});
```

...and who's intereseted in, here's the same for all coffee-junkies:

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = ->
  @each ->
    if document.body.createTextRange
      range = document.body.createTextRange()
      range.moveToElementText @
      range.select()
    else if window.getSelection
      selection = window.getSelection()
      range = document.createRange()
      range.selectNodeContents @
      selection.removeAllRanges()
      selection.addRange range
    return
```

**Update:**

If you want to select the entire page or contents of an editable region (flagged with `contentEditable`), you can do it much simpler by switching to `designMode` and using `document.execCommand`:

There's a good [starting point at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) and [a littledocumentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

```
var selectText = function () {
  document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
};
```

(works well in IE6+, Opera 9+, Firefoy 3+, Chrome 2+) http://caniuse.com/#search=execCommand

Answer (score 20):

The modern way of doing things is like this. More details on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/selectAllChildren)

```js
document.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
  window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(event.target)
})
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Fwiw, that MDN page marks this technology as experimental. But it works in the current version of Chrome and FF in June 2020.

Comment: Selecting only on mouse events is not feasible. User can select text with keyboard, too.

Comment: Thanks, this is the simple and best example for me!

Answer (score 11):

Since all of the existing answers deal with `div` elements, I'll explain how to do it with `span`s.

There is a subtle difference when selecting a text range in a `span`. In order to be able to pass the text start and end index, you have to use a `Text` node, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart):

> If the startNode is a Node of type Text, Comment, or CDATASection,
>   then startOffset is the number of characters from the start of
>   startNode. For other Node types, startOffset is the number of child
>   nodes between the start of the startNode.

```
var e = document.getElementById("id of the span element you want to select text in");
var textNode = e.childNodes[0]; //text node is the first child node of a span

var r = document.createRange();
var startIndex = 0;
var endIndex = textNode.textContent.length;
r.setStart(textNode, startIndex);
r.setEnd(textNode, endIndex);

var s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(r);
```

Comment: Really should be:
 
```r.setStart(e.firstChild,0); r.setEnd(e.lastChild,e.lastChild.textContent.length);```

Of course you should check that e.firstChild is actually not null.

Comment: There is no difference between making a selection in a `<div>` and a `<span>` element. At least, not as you describe.

Comment: There are differences between div and span, in some cases a solution for div doesn't work right in span. For example if you select text programmatically with div solution then paste new content, it will replace not the whole text, only a part and there are differences between chrome and firefox

Answer (score 6):

Rangy allows you to do this cross-browser with the same code. Rangy is a cross-browser implementation of the DOM methods for selections. It is well tested and makes this a lot less painful. I refuse to touch contenteditable without it.

You can find rangy here:

http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

With rangy in your project, you can always write this, even if the browser is IE 8 or earlier and has a completely different native API for selections:

```
var range = rangy.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableNode);
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Where "contentEditableNode" is the DOM node that has the contenteditable attribute. You might fetch it like this:

```
var contentEditable = document.getElementById('my-editable-thing');
```

Or if jQuery is part of your project already and you find it convenient:

```
var contentEditable = $('.some-selector')[0];
```

Comment: The Rangy project moved to Github now: https://github.com/timdown/rangy

Answer (score 2):

[Updated to fix mistake]

Here is an example that is adapted from this answer that appears to work well in Chrome - [Select range in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771824/select-range-in-contenteditable-div)

```
var elm = document.getElementById("myText"),
    fc = elm.firstChild,
    ec = elm.lastChild,
    range = document.createRange(),
    sel;
elm.focus();
range.setStart(fc,1);
range.setEnd(ec,3);
sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

HTML is:

```
<div id="myText" contenteditable>test</div>
```

Comment: how to add a background color to the selection text ?