# Mapping plain text back into HTML document

Tags: html, dom, annotations, mapping

**Situation:** I have a group of strings that represent [Named Entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) that were extracted from something that *used* to be an HTML doc. I also have both the original HTML doc, the stripped-of-all-markup plain text that was fed to the NER engine, and the offset/length of the strings *in the stripped file*.

I need to annotate the original HTML doc with highlighted instances of the NEs. To do that I need to do the following:

1. Find the start / end points of the NE strings *in the HTML doc*. Something that resulted in a [DOM Range Object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) would probably be ideal.
2. Given that Range object, apply a styling (probably using something like `<span class="ne-person" data-ne="123">...</span>`) to the range. This is tricky because there is no guarantee that the range won't include multiple DOM elements (`<a>`, `<strong>`, etc.) and the span needs to start/stop correctly within each containing element so I don't end up with totally bogus HTML.

Any solutions (full or partial) are welcome. The back-end is mostly Python/Django, and the front-end is using jQuery. We would rather do this on the back-end, but I'm open to anything.

(I was a bit iffy on how to tag this question, so feel free to re-tag it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [range utility method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element) plus an annotation library such as one of the following:

- [artisan.js](https://github.com/davidbrooks/Artisan)
- [annotator.js](https://github.com/openannotation/annotator)
- [vie.js](https://github.com/szabyg/vie-annotation-bookmarklet)

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'll check them out in the next couple days.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. Your answer pointed me in some interesting directions -- not exactly where I thought they would, but interesting nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The free software [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) JavaScript library is your friend. Regarding your two tasks:

1. **Find the start / end points of the […] strings in the HTML doc.** You can use [`Range#findText()`](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module#findtextmixed-searchterm-object-options) from the [TextRange](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module) extension. It indeed results in a DOM Level 2 Range compatible object [[source](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Range#introduction)].
2. **Given that Range object, apply a styling […] to the range.** This can be handled with the [Rangy Highlighter](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Highlighter-Module) module. If necessary, it will use multiple DOM elements for the highlighting to keep up a DOM tree structure.

*Discussion:* Rangy is a cross-browser implementation of the DOM Level 2 range utility methods proposed by @Paul Sweatte. Using an annotation library would be a further extension on range library functionality; for example, Rangy will be the basis of Annotator 2.0 [[source](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/latest/roadmap.html#id4)]. It's just not required in your case, since you only want to render highlights, not allow users to add them.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent possibility. Once I recover my health and get going on my project again it will be near the top of my Check This Out list. Thanks!