# How to select the text of a TinyMCE field with robot framework and selenium2library

Tags: tinymce, plone, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to select the text of a TinyMCE field with selenium2library keywords (in Plone).

I tried to select the text with mouse events (Mouse Down/Over/Up), Javascript and "Double Click Element" but nothing worked so far. The code below works if I set a debugger and select the text manually:

```
  Go to  ${PLONE_URL}/++add++Document
  Input Text  name=form.widgets.IDublinCore.title  My Document
  Select frame  id=form.widgets.text_ifr
  Input text  id=content  Lorem Ipsum
  # Attempt with Javascript
  Execute Javascript  document.getElementById("content").select()
  # Attempt with Double Click
  Double Click Element  xpath=//body[@id='content']/p[1]
  Double Click Element  id=content
  # Attempt with Mouse Events
  Mouse Down  xpath=//body[@id='content']/p[contains(text(),'L')]
  Mouse Over  xpath=//body[@id='content']/p[contains(text(),'orem')]
  Mouse Up  xpath=//body[@id='content']/p[contains(text(),'Ipsum')]
  # When I set a debug statement here and select the text manually the test passes
  Unselect Frame
  Click Link  id=form.widgets.text_link
  Wait until page contains element  id=mce_31_ifr
  Select frame  id=mce_31_ifr
  Click Link  News
  ...
```

It would already help if someone could recommend which method is most promising.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a rehash of a [JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element) here. For content-editable elements, I think JavaScript is the way to go. The following code selects the entire body of the content-editable portion of the TinyMCE widget.

```
Open Browser    http://www.tinymce.com/    gc
Select Frame    id=editMe_ifr
Input Text    id=tinymce    Lorem Ipsum
Execute Javascript    function selectElementContents(el) {var range = document.createRange(); range.selectNodeContents(el); var sel = window.getSelection(); sel.removeAllRanges(); sel.addRange(range);} var el = document.getElementById("tinymce"); selectElementContents(el);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The text in the TinyMCE field is now selected. Though, it seems that TinyMCE does not detect that (at least not in the test). The "Link"-button in the toolbar is still disabled (should be available as soon as text has been selected).

Comment: Hi Tisto, did you find how to do it?

Comment: I was able to get this to work with firefox, but it's not working with phantomjs.