# ckeditor: How to select all text inside editor on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for text formating and there is default text inside editor which I want to show selected on focus at all time.

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<textarea id="FirstTextEditor" >Hello</textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    CKEDITOR.instances.FirstTextEditor.on('focus', function () {
        // What is code i want write to select all text on focus?
    });
});
```

Comment: This might help moving forward: [HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange).

Comment: [The answer posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150060) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve what you want like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.["your instance here"].on( 'focus', function () { this.execCommand( 'selectAll' ); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used JQuery, it would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').focus(function(e){
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                that.select()
            }, 0);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/s6Z82/5/

The only thing you now have to figure out is how do you get the current element from the CKEDITOR.instances.FirstTextEditor.on callback and you are done.

**Why the setTimeout(.., 0)?**

Cause seems in Chrome e.preventDefault() does not stop it from discarding the select and putting the cursor to the end of the line.