# angular js select all text from a range div and span elements to let user copy the selected text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, jqlite

I am trying to create a `select all` functionality (in angular js) of some text which appears in a format similar to the structure given below. When all text is selected, then user could hit `ctrl + c` to copy the same.

```
<div ="container">
 <div class="header">My example header</div>
  <div class="section1">
    <span>test content1</span>
    <span>test content2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
    <span>test content3</span>
    <span>test content4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer content</div>
</div>
```

There will be a button, by click on it, all the text appearing inside the `container` div is required to be selected. I have searched many examples, so far all the examples I found is giving solutions on how to select text from a textarea or textbox. I wanted to find out how do I select all text from such range of html elelments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150060/2363552

Here is a plnkr of it working: [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lc20GSrG9sRUrFHy40iG?p=preview)

Javascript

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="header">My example header</div>
    <div class="section1">
        <span>test content1</span>
        <span>test content2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
        <span>test content3</span>
        <span>test content4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer content</div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="selectElementContents(document.getElementById('container'))">Select Text</button>
```