# jQuery Tablesorter, Focus to select the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, html-input

I would like to select the content of a Tablesorter cell using JQuery.

For example
I applied the method setSelectionRange in a input text. 
Good auto select text.

```
<input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" value="Sample Text" />
```

I want same effect to the content of a Tablesorter cell (DIV)

```
<div class="" contenteditable="true">0,00</div>
```

How to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using the [editable widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html) for my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8w5x7e1s/1/))

```
$('div[contenteditable]').on('focus', function() {
  var cell = this;
  // select all text in contenteditable
  // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150060/145346
  var range, selection;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(cell);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(cell);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

If you are using the editable widget, then use the [`editable_selectAll` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html#editable-selectall).

---

Update: this method works as well ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8w5x7e1s/2/))

That is, if your browser supports it  - see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=execCommand) & [this demo](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/QbLLGW).

```
$('div[contenteditable]').on('focus', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.execCommand('selectAll', false, null);
  }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I applied the second script works perfectly. Although I did not understand why it works

TNX