# Select text in htmlOutput based on datatable in shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I have the following shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Datatable for dynamic text selection"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        dataTableOutput("pairs")
      ),
      mainPanel(
       strong("Sentence"), htmlOutput("content"),
       strong("Selection"),textOutput("selection")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$content <- renderText("A sample sentence for demo purpose")
   df <- data.frame(SrNo=1:5, Pairs=c("A sample", "sample sentence", 
                                      "sentence for", "for demo", "demo purpose"))
   output$pairs <- renderDataTable(datatable(df, selection = "single" ))

   observeEvent(input$pairs_cell_clicked,{
     info = input$pairs_cell_clicked
    if(is.null(info$value)) return()
    output$selection <- renderText(info$value)
   })
   }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The app displays a sentence in `htmlOutput` and corresponding pair of words in `datatable`. At present clicking any of the pair of words in datatable displays it under the `Selection`.

**How can I modify the code so that instead of displaying the pair of words, it appears as selection in `htmlOutput`?**

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate how do you want the output to look like? with a screenshot may be?

Comment: I have selected `sample sentence` by myself using mouse, as shown in the screenshot, I would like this selection to be done by selecting pairs in datatable

Comment: What should happen when you select `2` instead of sample sentence there?

Comment: Nothing should happen if `2` is selected, the interaction is meant to select pair of words only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to wrap the selected text in a `span` with a CSS attribute to change the background color.

In your server.R, you could try (ellipsis where code doesn't change):

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  sample_text = "A sample sentence for demo purpose";
  output$content <- renderText(sample_text)

  .....

  observeEvent(input$pairs_cell_clicked,{

   .....

    output$content <- renderText(HTML(gsub(info$value,paste0("<span style='background-color:orange'>",info$value,"</span>"),sample_text)))
  })
}
```

EDIT:

To mimic the user selecting the text using his mouse you could do:

```
select_text = JS(
                 'table.on("click.td", "tr", function () {
                            contentdiv = document.getElementById("content");
                            var selectedCell=this.lastChild;
                            var sentence = contentdiv.innerHTML;
                            var target = selectedCell.innerHTML;
                            var sentenceIndex = sentence.indexOf(target); 
                            selection = window.getSelection();
                            range = document.createRange();
                            range.setStart(contentdiv.firstChild, sentenceIndex);
                            range.setEnd(contentdiv.firstChild, (sentenceIndex + target.length));
                            selection.removeAllRanges();
                            selection.addRange(range);
                  })'
              )                                              



server <- function(input, output) {
  sample_text = "A sample sentence for demo purpose";
  output$content <- renderText(sample_text)
  df <- data.frame(SrNo=1:5, Pairs=c("A sample", "sample sentence", 
                                     "sentence for", "for demo", "demo purpose"))
  output$pairs <- renderDataTable({datatable(df, selection = "single", callback=select_text)})

  observeEvent(input$pairs_cell_clicked,{
    info = input$pairs_cell_clicked
    if(is.null(info$value)) return()
    output$selection <- renderText(info$value)  
    })
}
```

JS inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse).

Comment: Highlighting would not help. I really need to select the pair in the sentence, as I further plan to provide buttons to extend the selection to the left and right of the pair.

Comment: can you translate select to programming terms? You could use `regexpr` to get the index of the match

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139107/programatically-select-text-in-a-contenteditable-html-element) is somehow related. Sorry that I am unable to come up with the exact terminology

Comment: Hum ok, I still think it's easier to use a `span` here, you can easily extend the `span` by moving the tags one word up of down using regexp and retrieve the text between it as well.

Comment: If you used a textAreaInput maybe a selection like the one you posted could work?

Comment: I want the click on datatable entries to serve as convenience for selection. If the user has to make selection on his own, he will have to click and drag using mouse.

Comment: I see, so you want to mimick a click and drag using the mouse programatically when the user clicks on the datatable. Something like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137032/discussion-between-imran-ali-and-nice).