# Transform String into Array and Select matching words inside the textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
  var ths = $(this);
  var array = $(this).val().split(' ');
  array.forEach(function(value){
    if (value.match(/(threewords)/g)) {
        ths.val().select(value);
    }
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>word twowords threewords</textarea>
```

What I want to do is to `select` the matching `text` inside the `textarea` if it matches the `.match(/(threewords)/g)` if I wrote `word`,

The problem is that I keep getting that `.match()` is `null` if there is no match or getting `select is not a function` if the match exists, But nothing is selected and the error occurs, How can I do what i'm trying to do properly?

Comment: What is `.select()` supposed to do? What are you trying to do in this loop?

Comment: @Kokogino I'm supposed to write multiple words, Then turn them into array for each word, After that I check if one of these words is equal to `word`, If it is Then I want to `select` it to change it. Like highlighting but `selecting` this specific word.

Comment: try ths.val(value) instead of .select

Comment: @Goran.it Tried it, It clears all the `textarea`  then types the last value in the `array` only. I used `ths.val(value).select();`

Comment: So you want to highlight every occurence of "word"?

Comment: @Kokogino Yes, but Highlighting seemed to require plugins, And in both cases the Highlighted text will be changed, So I thought selecting would be fit for this.

Comment: look, I don't think there is a straight forward way of programmatically selecting text (you will need plugins/tools), which seems to be what you are trying to do. after you match the text you want to select, [read on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150060/4770813)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('textarea').on('keyup', function(){
  var wordToSearch = 'threewords'
  var reg = new RegExp('\\b' + wordToSearch + '\\b')
  var indexStart = $(this).val().search(reg)
  if(indexStart >= 0){
    this.selectionStart = indexStart;
    this.selectionEnd = indexStart + wordToSearch.length;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>word twowords threewords</textarea>
```

This code selects `threewords` if it is written in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

the match() function returns the matches in an array of strings, i put up an example to demonstrate it easier

try it like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log('click');

  var tarea = $('textarea');
  var r = tarea.val().match(/(word)/g);
  console.log(r);
  console.log('jobs done');
});
```

try it out on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thregon/r6bs3x8s/)

what else you then want to do depends on what you need, if you just want to know if there is a match you can simply do so by checking if the returned array is empty or not.

in this case i use a button to trigger the check for convenience

edit: version without button [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thregon/r6bs3x8s/10)

Comment: I checked using `if (value.match(/(threewords)/g))` the problem occurs in the `select`ing the inner text.

Comment: @Toleo ok I think you only need to add word-boundary to the regex value.match(/\b(word)\b/g)

http://refiddle.com/refiddles/5ad600fd75622d4f2f200000

Answer (score 1):

`.select` doesn't work like you are intending it to.

1. `$("#target").select(value)` is incorrect syntax. `$("#target").select()` is a valid syntax but it does not highlight anything it triggers the `select` event on an element with id 'target'.
2. The `select` event is fired when any text is selected, as in, clicked and dragged over by the mouse. It can be handled by attaching a handler to it:

Example:

```
    $( "#target" ).select(function() {
        $( "div" ).text( "Something was selected" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
    });
```

`ths.val().select(value);` part of your code is not a function indeed. Hence the error.

`ths.val().select();` on the other hand ends up triggering the `select` event on the matched value which doesn't serve your purpose.