# Select range in contenteditable div (round 2)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

As a follow up to [Select range in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771824/select-range-in-contenteditable-div/47558123#47558123)

Stackoverflow doesn't allow me comment to Tim's "answer", but I've just tried the Tims code into jsfiddle and I don't see it working on Chrome or Edge now, maybe it worked on an earlier browser

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
var startNode = mainDiv.firstChild.firstChild;
var endNode = mainDiv.childNodes[2].firstChild;

var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, 6); // 6 is the offset of "world" within "Hello world"
range.setEnd(endNode, 7); // 7 is the length of "this is"
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/zc7kwar8/1/

Edge throws the console error "Invalid argument" pointing at the range.setStart command (line 6), and the Chrome console says "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'" on the same range.setStart line.

Does anyone have an suggestion on how to make this work on a "modern" browser? (Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Thanks Abe

Comment: `console.log(startNode, endNode);` right after you declare and define them, both are `null`. The firstChild of mainDiv is not the element, but the textNode created from white space between the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact `startNode` and `endNode` are `undefined`, because by `mainDiv.firstChild` and `mainDiv.childNodes[2]` you were pointing to 2 text nodes, which don't have child elements, that's why you will get `undefined` by calling `firstChild` upon them.

In fact these `text` nodes are created by the fact you make a new line between all your tags, so you need to point to the right `elements`.

This is how should your `startNode` and `endNode` be defined:

```
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
var startNode = mainDiv.childNodes[1].firstChild;
var endNode = mainDiv.childNodes[5].firstChild;
```

**Demo:**

```js
var mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
var startNode = mainDiv.childNodes[1].firstChild;
var endNode = mainDiv.childNodes[5].firstChild;
console.dir(mainDiv.childNodes);
console.log(endNode);
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(startNode, 6); // 6 is the offset of "world" within "Hello world"
range.setEnd(endNode, 7); // 7 is the length of "this is"
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

```html
<div id="main" contenteditable="true" style="border:solid 1px black; width:300px; height:300px">
  <div id='one'>Hello world!</div>
  <div id='two'>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div id='three'>This is a paragraph</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that white space between tags in HTML creates `textNode`s between your elements, and these count as children when using `childNodes`. Your `startNode` and `endNode` variables are actually `null` because `mainDiv.firstChild` is referring to a textNode and textNodes do not have children. Your variables should instead be:

```
var startNode = mainDiv.childNodes[1].firstChild;
var endNode = mainDiv.childNodes[5].firstChild;
```

See the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zc7kwar8/3/

Comment: Indeed. Using console logs you could have easily debug what was happening. Heres and update fiddles as well with the logs: https://jsfiddle.net/zc7kwar8/4/