# How to programmatically select text from string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble restoring selected text with javascript 
When the user selects some text from page A with the mouse. That selection is saved in localStorage.

I was able to store the selected string. I intend to restore the selection using

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
    restoreSelection();
});
```

However, I cannot restore that string. Here is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
    $(".main").mouseup(function () {


        var range, sel;
        var colour = 'yellow';

        if (window.getSelection) {
            // IE9 and non-IE
            try {
                if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                    makeEditableAndHighlight();
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight()
            }

        }
    });
    
    
function makeEditableAndHighlight() {
    var colour = 'yellow';
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";

    saveSelections(sel);
}


function saveSelections(selection) {

    if(selection){
        var highlight = selection.toString();
        // localStorage.setItem('textSelection', highlight);


    }

}


function restoreSelection() {
//var highlight = localStorage.getItem('textSelection');

    
if (highlight) {
 
     //I am stumped here I have tried 
       //CreateRange() but nothing works
    }

}
```

```css
div.storyText * ::selection {
    background: #FFFF00; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
  }
  div.storyText * ::-moz-selection {
    background: #FFFF00; /* Gecko Browsers */
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main ">

<p>Blalalalalalalalalalalalalala lorem ipsum text textstsetew </p>
</div>
```

**Does anyone have any idea? Thanks**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse - might you mean something like this?

Comment: @Babydead not really because I want to select a specific string inside any div.

Comment: Can't you just wrap that saved selection in a span on render and then select said span? Otherwise, this answer might help as well; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771824/select-range-in-contenteditable-div either way, you'll want your research to focus on "Select range" as keywords, I believe. I created a function myself to select things through selecting ranges once, but it wasn't this specific, unfortunately.